# Need help wireless rtx_8822bu

Tags: drivers, wireless

I need to make the wireless dongle work and when I looked in terminal I can see that it is there by commanding `lshw -C network`.  I get this:

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 5
       bus info: usb@3:2
       logical name: wlx347de44031b6
       serial: 34:7d:e4:40:31:b6
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822bu driverversion=6.2.0-33-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

So I looked for `rtw-8822bu` in the software files but I don't see it.  I tried using commands I found someone else used (I know it's crazy but I tried) and my terminal didn't recognize `git` so I installed `git`. Now I am scared I did something wrong and I am paralyzed with fear.

Can anyone advise me?  I am using my ethernet connection to try to make the dongle work on this computer.

Comment: Welcome. Everything will be OK in the end. Start with https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos . [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1487762/edit) to add information. Don't add information in comments.

Comment: Answers will end here, so check here for updates. According to [kernel.org Git repo](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88), drivers for this device should be included in the mainline kernels. So it should not be necessary to install any other drivers.